# 2 elements rotating but they are changing speed while it should be constant

Tags: javascript, css

[7s / 11s mark (4x Speed up)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iL8K4.gif)

So the red one is children of the blue one, when the blue one rotates, the red one too. But, the red one also have its own rotating speed. The problem is that the red one's speed isn't constant, probably because I am using 2 setInterval functions that are responsible for both rotating's time... So, for example, each 2 seconds the blue moves 10 px and each 1 second the red moves 5px. Every odd second, red moves 5px. Every even second, red moves 15px. How can I keep it the same?

```js
r_moon = 100; // radius
r_earth = 200;
a = 0;
b = 0;

function rotate_moon(a) {
  var px_moon = r_moon * Math.cos(a);
  var py_moon = r_moon * Math.sin(a);

  document.querySelector('#moon').style.left = px_moon + "px";
  document.querySelector('#moon').style.top = py_moon + "px";
}

function rotate_earth(b) {
  var px_earth = r_earth * Math.cos(b);
  var py_earth = r_earth * Math.sin(b);

  document.querySelector('#earth').style.left = px_earth + "px";
  document.querySelector('#earth').style.top = py_earth + "px";
}


setInterval(function moon() {
  a = (a + Math.PI / 360) % (Math.PI * 2);
  rotate_moon(a);
}, 10);

setInterval(function earth() {
  b = (b + Math.PI / 360) % (Math.PI * 2);
  rotate_earth(b);
}, 50);
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#earth {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: blue;
}

#moon {
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div id="earth">
    <div id="moon"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any problems. That's how relative motion works, the `#moon`'s speed is constant to the `#earth`, but from your POV, when they move in opposite opposite directions, the `#moon`'s will appear to slow down and when they move in the same direction, it'll appear to speed up.

Comment: On a side note: does it have to be JS? (i.e. is this a JS homework?) It'd be much easier to use CSS animation. If it has to be JS (and not a homework), don't use `setInterval()`, try `requestAnimationFrame()` and update both in the same function.

Comment: I agree with @haolt. This is an eye illusion. Here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/PoyMMrw?editors=0011) where I used moment.js to get the rotation time of each. You will see it is quite perfect by +/- 1ms.

Comment: Nice @InSync!! Post that as an answer ;)

Comment: @haolt Didn't heard about relative motion before, but it makes sense now! Yes, it is a JS homework. I will have a look at requestAnimationFrame(). Thanks!

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette It is a bit advanced to me, but it will definelly be a good material to study. I also really liked the way to keep track of the duration of the full circle, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, your code is totally fine. However, `setTimeout` [might have a delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified), which you may not want.

Here's a pure CSS solution that is supposed to work more reliably (thanks to @LouysPatriceBessette for suggesting me to post this).

(I haven't seen any docs on browser delaying CSS animations and would appreciate it if somebody could find one.)

The HTML is simple and self-explanatory:

```html
<div id="solar-system">
  <div class="body star" id="sun">
    <div class="body planet" id="earth">
      <div class="body satellite" id="moon"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I make `#earth` orbits `#sun` using a `transform`-ation on `#sun`, and `#moon` using another one on `#earth`. Self-rotations is omitted for simplicity.

```css
/* "body" as in celestial bodies */
.body {
  /* Center the child body */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  animation: rotate linear infinite;
  animation-duration: calc(var(--duration) / var(--speed));
}
```

Try it [on codepen.io](https://codepen.io/InSyncWithFoo/pen/NWOQQJN) (with Pug and Sass).

Try it:

```css
:root {
  --universe-color: #000;
  --sun-color: #ff0;
  --sun-radius: 15px;
  --sun-diameter: calc(var(--sun-radius) * 2);
  --earth-color: #2ea4d1;
  --earth-radius: 10px;
  --earth-orbital-period: 365.25s;
  --earth-to-sun-distance: 200px;
  --earth-diameter: calc(var(--earth-radius) * 2);
  --moon-color: #ddd;
  --moon-radius: 5px;
  --moon-orbital-period: 27.3s;
  --moon-to-earth-distance: 40px;
  --moon-diameter: calc(var(--moon-radius) * 2);
  --speed: 10;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  place-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#note {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: system-ui;
  z-index: 1;
}

#solar-system {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  place-items: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: var(--universe-color);
}

.body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  animation: rotate linear infinite;
  animation-duration: calc(var(--duration) / var(--speed));
}

#sun {
  --duration: var(--earth-orbital-period);
  height: var(--sun-diameter);
  background: var(--sun-color);
}

#earth {
  --duration: var(--moon-orbital-period);
  left: calc((var(--earth-to-sun-distance) + var(--earth-diameter)) * -1);
  height: var(--earth-diameter);
  background: var(--earth-color);
}

#moon {
  left: calc((var(--moon-to-earth-distance) + var(--moon-diameter)) * -1);
  height: var(--moon-diameter);
  background: var(--moon-color);
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    rotate: 0deg;
  }
  100% {
    rotate: 360deg;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="note">Not to scale</div>
<div id="solar-system">
  <div class="body star" id="sun">
    <div class="body planet" id="earth">
      <div class="body satellite" id="moon"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Again, **nice** solution! You definitely boosted my interest in Saas. ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette The *only* Sass-y thing in that sheet is [`@mixin`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin), really. The rest is handled by CSS natively thanks to our excellent browsers and new web standards.

Comment: @InSync Hey, thanks a lot for the answer! Actually this delay thing is kinda crazy. Also that way is really a better way to specify the duration of the orbit than using the math I did on my code. Now I can do full solar system xD.

Comment: @Dumb If that's the case, then you will have to modify the code a bit, as `#earth`'s revolution depends on how `#sun` is `rotate`-d. Also, your professor/teacher might be surprised to see a pure CSS solution when they have asked for a JS one...